# Какой функцией WinAPI можно извлечь N, P, Q и прочие параметры из приватного RSA-ключа?

Tags: winapi, криптография, rsa

Есть BLOB в микрософтовском формате, в нем - приватный RSA-ключ. Есть ли WinAPI-функции для извлечения модуля (N) и простых чисел (P, Q) из блоба? Вроде находил когда-то, снова найти не могу...

Answer (score 2):

[CryptExportKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379931(v=vs.85).aspx)

[RSA/Schannel Key BLOBs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387689(v=vs.85).aspx#privkrsablob)

```
modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
```

Пример кода (взято [отсюда](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/pfx_parse.cpp)):

```
   // Read the content of the PFX file
   FILE* pfxFile = _tfopen(argv[1], _T("rb"));
   if (!pfxFile)
   {
      _tprintf(_T("Failed to open PFX file for reading\n"));
      return -1;
   }

   long pfxLength = _filelength(_fileno(pfxFile));
   LPBYTE pbPfxData = (LPBYTE) LocalAlloc(0, pfxLength);
   fread(pbPfxData, 1, pfxLength, pfxFile);
   fclose(pfxFile);

   // Decrypt the content of the PFX file
   CRYPT_DATA_BLOB pfxBlob;
   pfxBlob.cbData = pfxLength;
   pfxBlob.pbData = pbPfxData;

   HCERTSTORE hPfxStore = PFXImportCertStore(&pfxBlob, szPassword, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE);
   if (!hPfxStore)
   {
      if (!szPassword)
      {
         // Empty password case. Try with empty string as advised by MSDN
         hPfxStore = PFXImportCertStore(&pfxBlob, L"", CRYPT_EXPORTABLE);
      }
      else if (wcslen(szPassword) == 0)
      {
         // Empty password case. Try with NULL as advised by MSDN
         hPfxStore = PFXImportCertStore(&pfxBlob, NULL, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE);
      }
   }

   if (!hPfxStore)
   {
      _tprintf(_T("Failed to decrypt PFX file content. Please check you typed the correct password"));
      goto ret;
   }

   // Enumerate all certificate on the PFX file
   PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
   DWORD dwTotalCertsCount = 0;
   DWORD dwCertsWithKeyCount = 0;
   DWORD cbSize = 0;
   PCRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO pKeyInfo = NULL;
   LPTSTR szValue = NULL;

   while( (pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hPfxStore, pCertContext)) )
   {
      dwTotalCertsCount++;

      // display certificate
      cbSize = CertNameToStr(X509_ASN_ENCODING, &pCertContext->pCertInfo->Subject, CERT_X500_NAME_STR, NULL, 0);
      szValue = (LPTSTR) LocalAlloc(0, cbSize * sizeof(TCHAR));
      CertNameToStr(X509_ASN_ENCODING, &pCertContext->pCertInfo->Subject, CERT_X500_NAME_STR, szValue, cbSize);

      // Print subject
      if (IsCACert(pCertContext))
         _tprintf(_T("\n%d) CA certificate.\n"), dwTotalCertsCount);
      else
         _tprintf(_T("\n%d) User certificate.\n"), dwTotalCertsCount);
      _tprintf(_T("   => Subject : %s\n"), szValue);
      LocalFree(szValue);

      // Print issuer
      cbSize = CertNameToStr(X509_ASN_ENCODING, &pCertContext->pCertInfo->Issuer, CERT_X500_NAME_STR, NULL, 0);
      szValue = (LPTSTR) LocalAlloc(0, cbSize * sizeof(TCHAR));
      CertNameToStr(X509_ASN_ENCODING, &pCertContext->pCertInfo->Issuer, CERT_X500_NAME_STR, szValue, cbSize);
       _tprintf(_T("   => Issuer  : %s\n"), szValue);
      LocalFree(szValue);

      // Check if it has a private key
      if (CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, 
              CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID,
              NULL,
              &cbSize)
         )
      {
         dwCertsWithKeyCount++;
         // Get private key components
         pKeyInfo = (PCRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO) LocalAlloc(0, cbSize);
         if (CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, 
                 CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID,
                 pKeyInfo,
                 &cbSize)
            )
         {
            // Acquire a context and export the private key
            HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
            HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
            BOOL bStatus = CryptAcquireContextW(&hProv, 
               pKeyInfo->pwszContainerName,
               pKeyInfo->pwszProvName,
               pKeyInfo->dwProvType,
               pKeyInfo->dwFlags);
            if (bStatus)
            {
               bStatus = CryptGetUserKey(hProv, pKeyInfo->dwKeySpec, &hKey);
               if (bStatus)
               {
                  bStatus = CryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, NULL, &cbSize);
                  if (bStatus)
                  {
                     LPBYTE pbBlob = (LPBYTE) LocalAlloc(0, cbSize);
                     bStatus = CryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, pbBlob, &cbSize);
                     if (bStatus)
                     {
                        // Display the RSA private key
                        DisplayPrivateKey(pbBlob, cbSize);
                     }
                     SecureZeroMemory(pbBlob, cbSize);
                     LocalFree(pbBlob);
                  }

                  CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
               }
               CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);

               // Delete the key and its container from disk
               // We don't want the key to be persistant
               CryptAcquireContextW(&hProv, 
                  pKeyInfo->pwszContainerName,
                  pKeyInfo->pwszProvName,
                  pKeyInfo->dwProvType,
                  CRYPT_DELETEKEYSET);
            }
         }

         LocalFree(pKeyInfo);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Спасибо, там они через структуру это делают, наверное нет нужной API.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Просто там поля с нефиксированными размерами

Comment: вот и хочется API типа result = GetKeyParam(hKey, RSA_PARAM_N, buffer. bufferLen). Многие функции могут сообщать размеры буфера, требуемого для операции.